# Logic Pro X keeps making my tracks HUGE whenever I click on the track, won't stop doing it!

Tags: logic-pro, issue

Whenever I click on the track (to unmute it, to click it to re-order it, or just simply click the track) all the tracks become big, if I click them in any way again they get even bigger, and this continues until the tracks are humungous.

Someone here advised <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> but what I discovered is pressing this just shrinks them back down to big, but not compact as they normally appear when you first open a project.

This suddenly began happening, and I haven't been able to find a way to stop it or a way to easily condense them back to the original anytime this happens. In the course of working on a song, this will happen so many times, it also happens whenever I click the back button or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and sometimes even after recording.

[image: Here's a play by play of what happens starting with how the project opens, then what happens after the first, second, and third click, and then what happens when I press control Z]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a basic customer support question, better addressed to the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: What happens if you turn off the automation lanes view?